# How to paste 2 images of different sizes onto same background using cv2?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I would like to paste 2 images of different sizes onto a same background using cv2.

I found codes, example below that can only merge equal size images which is a limitation.

```
import cv2 as cv
    
img_0 = cv.imread("0.tiff")
img_1 = cv.imread("1.tiff")
    
bg_img = cv.imread("5120x2048 black.png")
        
bg_img[0:0+img_0.shape[0], 0:0+img_0.shape[1]] = img_0
bg_img[0:0+img_1.shape[0], 512*4:512*4+img_1.shape[1]] = img_1
        
cv.imwrite("bg_img.tiff", bg_img)
```

From the above code, if I set:

```
bg_img[0:0+img_1.shape[0]+10, 512*4:512*4+img_1.shape[1]] = img_1
```

it will produce an error message:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (512,512,3) into shape (522,512,3)
```

I have prepared 3 images and I hope to be able to set coordinates to place the 2 images on the white background so that all 3 images form a single image.

```
[Star](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnY7D.png)
[Triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDt6C.png)
[White background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5etY.png)
```

The star image is 100x100 pixels^2. The triangle image is 200x200 pixels^2. The white background is 700x700 pixels^2.

Let's say, coordinate (0,0) be the top left starting point for star. Coordinate (250,250) be the top left starting point for the triangle.

Many thanks.

Comment: Your 512px tall image can't fill a space 522px tall.

Comment: Thank you, I got what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2 as cv
    
img_0 = cv.imread("Star.png")
img_1 = cv.imread("Triangle.png")
    
bg_img = cv.imread("White.png")
        
bg_img[0:0+img_0.shape[0], 0:0+img_0.shape[1]] = img_0
bg_img[250:250+img_1.shape[0], 250:250+img_1.shape[1]] = img_1
        
cv.imwrite("bg_img.tiff", bg_img)
```

[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOX3z.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).